# Joining binary intervals of a given distance

Tags: r

I have a series of zones defined by a value of 1, and I need to join zones that have a space of fewer than two cells by replacing those 0 values with 1. For example, cell df[11,1] needs to be replaced by a 1, and cells df[15:16,1] need to be replaced with 1's, while cells df[21:23,1] should remain as 0's.

```
> df <-  data.frame("Zone" = 1:25)
> df[1] <- 0
> df <-  data.frame("Zone" = 1:25)
> df[1] <- 0
> df[4:10,1] <- 1
> df[12:14,1] <- 1
> df[17:20,1] <- 1
> df[24:25,1] <- 1
> df
   Zone
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    0
12    1
13    1
14    1
15    0
16    0
17    1
18    1
19    1
20    1
21    0
22    0
23    0
24    1
25    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to get the run-length-encoding-id based on the difference in adjacent elements of the column, then get the row index (`.I`) where the condition is met and update the 'Zone' by specifying the index in `i` while updating the 'Zone' to 1

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, grp := rleid(Zone)][, .I[Zone == 0 & .N <=2], grp]$V1

df[i1, Zone := 1][, grp  := NULL][]
#    Zone
# 1:    0
# 2:    0
# 3:    0
# 4:    1
# 5:    1
# 6:    1
# 7:    1
# 8:    1
# 9:    1
#10:    1
#11:    1
#12:    1
#13:    1
#14:    1
#15:    1
#16:    1
#17:    1
#18:    1
#19:    1
#20:    1
#21:    0
#22:    0
#23:    0
#24:    1
#25:    1
```

---

Or using `dplyr` by creating a group comparing the adjacent elements and then replacing the value with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(Zone != lag(Zone, default = first(Zone)))) %>%
    mutate(Zone = case_when(Zone == 0 & n() <=2 ~ 1, TRUE  ~Zone)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```

---

Or using `rle/inverse.rle` from `base R`

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df$Zone), values[values== 0 & lengths <=2] <- 1))
#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
```

Or it can be slightly made compact with

```
with(rle(df$Zone), +(rep((!values & lengths <=2)|values, lengths)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Zone = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -25L),
   class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `rle` from base R we can check for 0 values in `Zone` and change them to 1 if their length is less than equal to 2.

```
df$Zone[with(rle(df$Zone == 0), rep(values & lengths <= 2, lengths))] <- 1
df

#   Zone
#1     0
#2     0
#3     0
#4     1
#5     1
#6     1
#7     1
#8     1
#9     1
#10    1
#11    1
#12    1
#13    1
#14    1
#15    1
#16    1
#17    1
#18    1
#19    1
#20    1
#21    0
#22    0
#23    0
#24    1
#25    1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Zone = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), 
       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```